# Xcode 4.5.1 App Crashes

Tags: xcode, ios5, crash

Yesterday I updated XCode from 4.3 to 4.5.1 to work on iOS 6 and iphone 5 . I was opening my previous project compiling and running them on my iPad 2 (5.1.1) and everything works fine.

Today, I decided to work on a new project ,just to test every thing i selected a tabbed application and changed the deployment target to 4.3 but it wont work the app icon shows up on the iPad but crashes as soon as I open it.

UPDATE : when  i select a single view application(other dont work) from the new project menu and run it without changing anything it works but as soon as i add anything (even a label) it crashes .

my previous xcode problems:

2) xcode is never able to run an app directly . when i deploy them the app opens but crashes instantly then i tap the icon again at it runs fine

3) what do i have to do to target 4.2.1 ipods and iphones

log file

```
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?l6fcgq2lvqiby6o
```

Comment: Can you give any information about the crash, such as console messages or a stack trace?

Comment: Where are these message I seem to get no error .. All I get is some thing like " unable to run and get info from process XXX" ... I am trying a complete reinstall of lion at the moment .. Will see after that

Comment: @PhillipMills    Alright Now i am really worried i get a complete reinstall of lion and xcode 4.5.1 .. but the apps still crash the same way all i get is an error message saying

"Could not launch ball"
"failed to get the task for process 2073"